# Grub makeactive command in Grub2?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub

Currently i have GRUB2 with Ubuntu 9.10 installed, including 2 other O/S.
I have an entry for an o/s in my grub.cfg:

```
menuentry "My OS" {
    insmod ntfs
    rootnoverify (hd0,6)
        makeactive
        chainloader +1
}
```

However, when i run this, it says that the makeactive command does not exist. Ive already tried some things like 'active' and 'make active', but all give me the same error.

What is the makeactive command in Grub2?

Answer (score 3):

The makeactive command [has been replaced](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Commands) in GRUB2. You are now supposed to use parttool.

To set a partition's active flag with parttool:

```
parttool (hd0,6) boot+
```

and to remove it:

```
parttool (hd0,6) boot-
```

Comment: i tried this, and it said 'rootnoverify' does not exist. so i removed that line, but now it gives me 'error: not primary partition'. what to do?

Comment: Linux only allows 4 primary partitions. You appear to have the data installed to a non-primary partition. This is a different question which doesn't relate to makeactive though, and it seems you've already made another question for that purpose.

Comment: Yes, although it isnt answered, and only watched +/- 5 times in 1 hour.

Comment: to clarify, "4 primary partitions" isn't a Linux limitation, it's a limitation of the MBR partition table used to partition the drive.